# Problem with ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of files with raw data. I have a macro that goes through the selected files in a loop and put the data of each file onto one sheet in xlsm template for further calculations and evaluations.  That means, I end up with a xlsm file with corresponding Worksheet for each raw data file. The macro also creates a Result file (xlsx, from provided Results template) that contains 1 row of resuls and 1 graph from each Worksheet in xlsm file. I need each row of data and each line in the graph linked back to the original Worksheet in the xlsm file, so changes made in the xlsm file translate to the Resuls file.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
Sub AssembleResults()
'// Subroutine goes through every list in Workbook and copies row of results and graph to Resuls file

    Dim SingleSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet, 
    Dim wksDest As Worksheet    
    Dim rngSource, rngDest As Range            
    Dim chrtSource As ChartObject, chrtDest As Chart          
    
    '// Open Results template
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True   
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=XltResults, Editable:=True
    Set wbResults = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    For Each SingleSheet In wbTemplate.Worksheets      
        '//wbTemplate is berofe defined and used xlsm file with Worksheets

        Set wksSource = wbTemplate.Worksheets(SingleSheet.Name)
        Set rngSource = wksSource.Range("A3:L3")
        Set chrtSource = wksSource.ChartObjects(2)
            
        wbResults.Worksheets("Results").Activate
        Set wksDest = ActiveSheet
        Set rngDest = wksDest.Range(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(-1,0),Range("L1").End(xlDown).Offset(-1,0))
        
        Set chrtDest = wbResults.Charts(1)
            
        '//Copying row of results
        rngSource.Copy
        wbResults.Activate   
        wksDest.Activate     
        rngDest.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True          '//HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
          
        '//Copying lines of graph into single graph
        chrtSource.Activate
        chrtSource.Copy  
        wbResults.Activate
        chrtDest.Select
        chrtDest.Paste    
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        '// Cleaning the variables
        Set wksSource = Nothing
        Set wksDest = Nothing
        Set rngSource = Nothing
        Set rngDest = Nothing
        Set chrtSource = Nothing
        Set chrtDest = Nothing

End Sub
```

Randomly, on indicated line (while trying to paste the linked row), macro will throw:
`Run-time Error'1004': No Link to Paste`
However, if you step into debug mode and just press 'F5'/Run, it will run again without problem for random number of loops.

It's truly random. Some batches of data, macro runs without error. Other, errors occurs three times in a batch. If run more times on the same batch of data, it can run without error or randomly stop in any loop. There is no pattern I can see. I would appriciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get an answer here, but I managed to figure out solution on my own. So, for anyone interested, here it is.

Seems the problem is with copying anything to clipboard, especially, if user clicks anywhere while macro is running. To avoid this I swiched from copy/paste to assigning strings into formulas for cells in Row of Results and into NewSeries properties for Graph. Final code:

```
Sub AssembleResults()
'// Subroutine goes through every list in Workbook and copies row of results and graph to Resuls file

    Dim SingleSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wksDest As Worksheet    
    Dim rngDest As Range            
    Dim chrtDest As Chart
    Dim cel As Range     
    
    For Each SingleSheet In wbTemplate.Worksheets      
        '//wbTemplate is berofe defined and used xlsm file with Worksheets
        '//wbResults is berofe defined and opened xltx file

        Set wksDest = wbResults.Worksheets(1)
        Set rngDest = wksDest.Range(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(-1,0),Range("L1").End(xlDown).Offset(-1,0))
        Set chrtDest = wbResults.Charts(1)
            
        '//Linking row of results
        For Each cel In rngDest
            cel.Formula = "='" & wbTemplate.Path & "\[" & wbTemplate.Name & "]" & SingleSheet.Name & "'!" & Cells(3, cel.Column).Address
        Next cel
       
        '//Copying lines of graph into single graph
             '// RadekStart and
         With chrtDest.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "='[" & wbTemplate.Name & "]" & wshTemplate.Name & "'!$A$3"
            .Values = "='[" & wbTemplate.Name & "]" & wshTemplate.Name & "'!" & Range(Range("AB3"),Range("AB3").End(xlDown)).Address
            .XValues = "='[" & wbTemplate.Name & "]" & wshTemplate.Name & "'!" & Range(Range("AA3"),Range("AA3").End(xlDown)).Address
         End With

    Next SingleSheet
        
        '// Cleaning the variables
        Set wksDest = Nothing
        Set rngDest = Nothing
        Set chrtDest = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One day I had similar random problem on a Macro that always worked properly. The reason was I had swicthed on "clipboard history"  (windows key + V key).
just turn off cpliboard history and works fine...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34687357)